# Is it possible to mount a filesystem included in a FIT image?

Tags: linux, u-boot, device-tree

I an running an embedded board with U-Boot as the boot loader. I have created a basic FIT image that boots the Linux kernel with the device tree and RootFS images.
Currently I boot my FIT image with the command `tftpboot boot.itb && bootm`, which will boot the default configuration successfully. Shortly after the kernel boots I want to mount an additional read-only partition in RAM. This would be exposed as a mount point in Linux (for example, `/mnt/image`). This partition would be embedded in the FIT image itself rather than stored, for example, on flash.

Is this possible? With U-Boot I have my default configuration set to use my standard RootFS as the ramdisk, but can I have "two" ramdisks, one to boot from and one to mount?

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    description = "FIT Image";
    #address-cells = <1>;

    images {
        kernel@0 {
            description = "Linux Kernel";
            data = /incbin/("./vmlinux.bin.gz");
            type = "kernel";
            arch = "ppc";
            os = "linux";
            compression = "gzip";
            load = <0x00000000>;
            entry = <0x00000000>;
            hash@1 {
                algo = "sha1";
            };
        };
        fdt@0 {
            description = "Flattened Device Tree blob";
            data = /incbin/("./devicetree.dtb");
            type = "flat_dt";
            arch = "ppc";
            compression = "none";
            hash@1 {
                algo = "sha1";
            };
        };
        ramdisk@0 {
            description = "ramdisk";
            data = /incbin/("./rootfs.cpio.gz");
            type = "ramdisk";
            arch = "ppc";
            os = "linux";
            compression = "gzip";
            hash@1 {
                algo = "sha1";
            };
        };
    };
    configurations {
        default = "conf@1";
        conf@1 {
            description = "Boot Linux kernel with FDT blob + ramdisk";
            kernel = "kernel@0";
            fdt = "fdt@0";
            ramdisk = "ramdisk@0";
            hash@1 {
                algo = "sha1";
            };
        };
    };
};
```